# button for mute every SystemSound

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer, mute, system-sounds

I used `AVAudioPlayer`, but it's too laggy, if I use this code:

```
    NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MySound" ofType:@"caf"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &_MySound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);
```

There isn't any lagg.

But I have a button which mute/unmute everysound in my **app**. How can I mute these sounds like `mysound.volume = 0` in `AVAudioplayer`